# slider with dynamic images

Tags: php, database, slider

I have a slider and I get data from a database in this way:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `banners` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4"; 
$banners = $rs->get_object_list($sql); 

<?php foreach($banners as $ban) {  
$imagen="imagenes/banners/$ban->id/img.jpg"; ?> 

<img id="<?php echo $ban->id ?>" align="center" src="<?php echo $imagen ?>" class="slide" alt=""/> 

<?php } ?>


<script type="text/javascript">

 if(!window.slider) var slider={};  
 slider.data=[{"id":"1","client":"","desc":""},{"id":"2","client":"","desc":""},{"id":"3","client":"","desc":""},{"id":"4","client":"","desc":""}];

</script>
```

But I have an issue with this, if I upload for example 3 images the last one is the same than number 3, I think I need to program something dymanic, and I tried this code:

```
slider.data=[{"id":"slide-img-<?php echo $ban->id ?>","client":"","desc":""}];
```

But it doesn't work, hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.slider) var slider={};  
        slider.data= [
            <?php
                $resultstr = array();
                foreach ($banners as $ban) {
                    $resultstr[] = "{'id': $ban->id,'client':'','desc':''}";
                }
                $result = implode(",",$resultstr);
                echo $result;
            ?>];
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I tried with your example but it doesn't work, maybe the issue is in the last ","  

Take a look to this example, the last data is without "," 

    slider.data=[{"id":"1","client":"","desc":""},{"id":"2","client":"","desc":""},{"id":"3","client":"","desc":""},{"id":"4","client":"","desc":""}];

How can I do that?

Comment: Show me this error: Error de HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This happens when you have an error in your server side code, and the changes that I have made previously should not cause it. However, I went ahead and updated to even better code, try now.

Comment: Thank u very much! it's working! :)
I appreciate your time for helping me.